# Slugs Disappeared Leaving 404s - Quick way to repopulate?

Tags: permalinks, slug

I've got roughly 3000 pages in WordPress w/ permalinks on. I recently cleaned up the database which appears to have deleted a fair amount of slugs for many of the pages.

Obviously, with no slug, WordPress can't reference the page, therefore I or anyone else can't get to it.

Rather than go in, one at a time and fix the missing slugs - Does anyone know a quick way to repopulate them?

Comment: Have you tried flushing your permalinks? Just go to Settings -> Permalinks and save the page.

Comment: Indeed, I did try that. I even changed the structure. Where there was once a slug has now been replaced by two forward slashes. Wordpress literally sees the permalink as a blank entry.

Comment: This is why I make a backup before doing anything to a db. Check your GUIDs for each post in your posts table.